# flutter firebase push notification icon

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, icons, flutter-notification

I made an app and I implemented push notifications and it works but I've tried to change the default icon with a `image.png` but it's not working the way that I expected. This is how my notification looks: [image]

And I want my icon to look like this:

[image]

I've added in my android manifest this:

```
<!-- Add custom icon to the notifications -->
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_notifications" />
<!-- Change the color of the icon -->
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

I don't know what I've done wrong but can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `android:resource` (@`folder`/`name`)in the `meta-data` tag refers to the notification icon should be located in android\app\src\main\res\ `folder`-`size`\ `name`.png.

For your exact scope, you need the `drawable`-`size` folder in the specific location with pngs named `ic_notifications`. I suggest you use this [amazing tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_notification) to generate all the required icons with the correct layout (white on transparent).

Because you also have a color for your notification, you must add the `colors.xml` in `android/app/src/main/res/values` which will contain your `colorPrimary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

**Extra:** The `android:icon` in the `application` tag refers to the app's icon. Just want to add this extra piece of information because it can be confusing at first when the example found are pretty similar.