# how to add channel id to push Notification payload

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

i am using push notification with local notification.. i have to set channel id in my payload..
**here is my payload**

i am not sure if this is payload for both andriod and ios. please help me out with correct payload.

thanks

```
exports.chatFunctions = functions.firestore.document("chat/{chatId}/Messages/{messagesId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        console.log('No Device');
    }
    const chatDatas = snapshot.data();
    const messageTo = chatDatas['idTo'];
    const deviceTokenuUser1 = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(messageTo).get();
    const user1name = deviceTokenuUser1.data()['name'];
    const user1Url = deviceTokenuUser1.data()['profilePictureUrl'];

    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `${user1name}`,
            body: `${chatDatas['content']}`,
        },
        data: {
            key: 'chat',
            id: `${messageTo}`,
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
        },
        android: {
            priority: "high",
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    contentAvailable: true,
                },
            },
            headers: {
                "apns-push-type": "background",
                "apns-priority": "5", // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
                "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
            },
        },

        token: deviceTokenuUser1.data()['tokens'],
    };
    try {
        await admin.messaging().send(payload);

        console.log("Firebase chat Messaging Successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error from chat messaging " + err);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add channel id like this:

```
let payload = {
// ...
    android: {
        priority: "high",
        notification: {
            channelId: "yourchannelid"
        }
    }

// ...
}
```

Comment: what about the iOS and please add the click action of the ios to it

Comment: I think there is no channel id in iOS, and `click_action` should work with you original code.

Comment: so that payload will work for both android and iOS

Comment: you have to try